# How to fix "ERROR : Module 'cv2' has no attribute 'legacy' on python 3.7.9 and Windows 11"?

Tags: python, opencv, attributeerror, legacy

I installed **OpenCV version 4.5.2.52** to try and use super-resolution on pictures that I want to read but are too blurry.

To do so, I am following the code from this site: https://programmer.group/opencv-advanced-super-resolution-based-on-opencv.html

There are different codes on this page that I can copy, I wanted to try this one :

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read picture
img = cv2.imread("AI-Courses-By-OpenCV-Github.png")
img = img[5:60,700:755]
sr = cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()
path = "ESPCN_x3.pb"
sr.readModel(path)
sr.setModel("espcn",3)
result = sr.upsample(img)

# Resize image
resized = cv2.resize(img,dsize=None,fx=3,fy=3)
plt.figure(figsize=(6,2))
plt.subplot(1,3,1)

# original image 
plt.imshow(img[:,:,::-1])
plt.subplot(1,3,2)

# SR up sampling image
plt.imshow(result[:,:,::-1])
plt.subplot(1,3,3)

## Sampling images on OpenCV
plt.imshow(resized[:,:,::-1])
plt.show()
```

When I ran it I got the error "**AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'dnn_superres'**".
So I checked these pages "https://blog.csdn.net/qq_48455792/article/details/120258336" (translated from chinese) and  "https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/441" where it was written that for versions of openCV that are above 4.5.x, the libraries have been moved to 'legacy'.

I understood that I just had to change `sr = cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()` into `sr = cv2.legacy.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()` for it to work.

But with this change I got the error
`AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'legacy'`.

I checked the answer to the error on stackoverflow on these pages :

[I'm getting module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'legacy' ERROR. How can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67942853/im-getting-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-legacy-error-how-can-i-fix-it)

[AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633378/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer)

On both these pages, it was recommended either to install the contribution openCV or to install an older version than the one I have (4.4.0.46), but none of these worked in my case, so I don't know what to do now.

Could you help me ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have this problem anymore so I will share what I did to make it work.

As Christoph Rackwitz mentionned `opencv-contrib-python` alone works just fine with the version 4.5.5.62 (latest version) to use the function `cv2.dnn_superres`.

I personnally had to uninstall all previous installations dealing with opencv :

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

Then I deleted all files that had to do with opencv too : after the uninstallation a "***cv2***" file and "***opencv_contrib_python-4.5.2.52.dist-info***" remained and caused errors.

Once all these files were deleted I reinstalled opencv-contrib with the right version using :

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5.62
```

It appeared in the Python\Lib\site-packages directory and now I can use cv2 just fine.

Thank you for your help, I hope it will help others.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not** install both `opencv-python` and `opencv-contrib-python` at the same time. Install **only one** of both.

I can access `cv2.dnn_superres` in `opencv-contrib-python` version 4.5.5 (currently the latest).

Comment: Hello, 

I uninstalled `opencv-python`, `opencv-contrib-python` and `opencv-contrib-python-headless` to reinstall `opencv-contrib-python` version 4.5.5 using these commands `pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5` and `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5` but each time I go the error : `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5 (from versions: none)` and `ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5`.

Is the version 4.5.5.x ?

Comment: either don't specify a specific version, or specify the version completely. `==` does not accept substrings (afaik). `4.5.5` is a substring of what's available for these packages. check https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/ and please review the [tour]